# Freemind on Windows: EXE wrapper not recognizing OpenJDK

Tags: windows, java, openjdk, freemind

I am trying to run Freemind 1.0.1 on a Windows 10 machine with OpenJDK. When I try to launch it from the Start menu or try to open a `.mm` file in File Explorer, I get an error message saying

> This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.5.0.

In both cases, Windows presumably tries to run `C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeMind\FreeMind.exe` (launching it directly gives me the same result). The same folder also has a batch file `Freemind.bat`, which launches Freemind successfully.

I am running OpenJDK 13.0.2, and `java.exe` is on my default `PATH`.

Is there a way to get the EXE wrapper to play nicely with OpenJDK 13? Or is that a bug which is hard-coded into the binary?

Comment: Please provide your path variable

Answer (score 5):

Change the registry in this way depening on your installed JDK, then freemind.exe will work.
In my case a key for "Java Runtime Environment" was missing. I added the version info from the existing JDK-info.

Registry path:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\11]
```

Registry entry:

```
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-11.0.14.101-hotspot\\"
```

Comment: This worked perfect to get FreeMind running again! Thank YOu!

Comment: Worked even with Amazon Coretto JDK, as Amazon Coretto is JDK only distribution based on OpenJDK on Windows (doesn't have a JRE only distribution for Windows). Allowed me to fireup MindFree finally.

Answer (score 2):

I reached the same issue with openjdk 15 but noticed that I can use *"C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeMind\Freemind.**bat**"* successfully.

Here is what I did:

- I modified launcher in start menu to use *"C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeMind\Freemind.**bat**"* instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeMind\Freemind.**exe**"
- To solve file association issue which still links to exe , I opened the registry editor (regedit.exe) as admin,
  and modify HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Freemind\shell\open\command from
  *"C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeMind\freemind.**exe**"* "%1" to *"C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeMind\freemind.**bat**" "%1"*
- The **freemind.bat uses relative path** so launching from another location won't work : I also edited the Freemind.bat file, inserting a new line in the second line with the following : **cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeMind"** , the .bat file looks like this

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeMind"
java -Xmx256M -Xss8M -cp lib\freemind.jar;lib\commons-lang-2.0.jar;lib\forms-1.0.5.jar;lib\jibx\jibx-run.jar;lib\jibx\xpp3.jar;lib\bindings.jar;lib\xalan.jar;lib\serializer.jar;lib\xml-apis.jar;lib\xercesImpl.jar;lib\jortho.jar freemind.main.FreeMindStarter
```

It works fine for me with these 3 steps , hope this will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this - I ran into problems running Freemind as others have.
I resorted to using the .bat file but called by adding the following:
-Djava.security.manager=allow

So something like...

```
java -Djava.security.manager=allow  -Xmx256M -Xss8M -cp lib\freemind.jar;lib\commons-lang-2.0.jar;lib\forms-1.0.5.jar;lib\jibx\jibx-run.jar;lib\jibx\xpp3.jar;lib\bindings.jar;lib\xalan.jar;lib\serializer.jar;lib\xml-apis.jar;lib\xercesImpl.jar;lib\jortho.jar freemind.main.FreeMindStarter
```

Note: Credit to judovana over at https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules/issues/85  and https://openjdk.org/jeps/411